# Fractal dimension: Using differential box counting

Tags: grayscale, fractals

Most of the literature gives the method of estimating fractal dimension for grayscale images using differential box couting methods. But they considered only 8 bit images which has 256 gray levels. Can anyone give advice on how to select box height for 32-bit grayscale images. By following the existing methods I was getting FD value less than 2 which means the algorithm is wrong. I'm using the algorithm describes in this paper. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.measurement.2019.106859

Or should we consider a 32 bit grayscale image as rgb image?

I tried changing the box-height accordign to image size, grid size, standard deviation of pixel values, difference in maximum and minimum of pixel values. I couldnt get a promisisng result. Anyone with the expertise please suggest on how to proceed with this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Nr -number of box for a give r- is calculated based on G max (max value of the pixel in the box) and G min.
the algorithm is suitable for all gray level